# Show $X-Y $ is open and $ Y-X$ is closed in $R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

$X$ is open in $R^n$ and $Y$ is closed in $R^n$

I understand that for Y to be closed $R^n - Y$ must be open, but I guess I'm confused on how to prove what an open set. I also understand that if $f$ is a finite set of points, then $R^n - f$ is open.

Perhaps do i say that since X is open, and Y is closed, Y is a finite  set of points and thus $X-Y$ is open since im subtracting a finite set of points from an open subspace?

And conversely do the same thing for Y-X ?

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know what your definition of open and closed is. Assuming that you know that intersection of two opens is open, you can say that $X \setminus Y = X \cap (\mathbb{R}^n \setminus Y)$. Now, $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus Y$ is open because $Y$ is closed, so $X \setminus Y$ is intersection of two open sets, and thus and open set.

Answer (score 1):

$X-Y=X\cap(R^n-Y)$, it's open because both $X$ and $R^n-Y$ are open.

$Y-X=Y\cap(R^n-X)$, it's closed because both $Y$ and $R^n-X$ are closed.